# Qt: .pro file missing?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I tried to create a C++ project with Qt I stumbled across different kinds of guides which all refer to a special '.pro' file inside the project where I have to adjust a setting so the SQL part takes effect.

My problem: whenever I create a new project - doesn't matter whether its with qbs, qmake, or cmake - the project structure/ folder is lacking the '.pro' file.

Currently I'm using **Qt 5.15.2** (via **QT Creator**) with MinGW Kit and cmake/ qbs.

[image: Current project path]

As I'd like to play around with SQL-based apps.

Maybe I'm just skipping/ overlook something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: Use cmake. Forget about qbs and qmake.

> Whenever I create a new project - doesn't matter whether its with qbs, qmake, or cmake - the project structure/ folder is lacking the '.pro' file.

A qmake project will have the `.pro` file, since that's the project file for qmake. Maybe you're looking in a wrong place? A qbs project will have a `.qbs` file, since that's what qbs uses. A cmake project will have `CMakeLists.txt`, since that's what cmake uses. It all works for me.

> I'm just confused by all these guides stating that I have to add QT += widgets sql in the .pro file.

Those guides only apply when you use qmake, since `.pro` are qmake project files.

I suggest that you use cmake, as qbs is abandoned now, and there's no benefit to using Qt-specific qmake over the widely supported and continuously developed cmake.

Qt documentation covers [the basics of how to use cmake to build Qt projects](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-get-started.html#build-a-gui-executable).

Qt support is provided natively by cmake, [and it thus provides a comprehensive reference page](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-qt.7.html).